# How to debug safari extension popover?

Tags: safari-extension, popover

How to open javascript console for extension popover in safari?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like Apple forgot to provide a way to open a console for a popover.

To somewhat facilitate debugging a popover, you can use the console.log() method of the extension's global page from a script in the popover:

```
  safari.extension.globalPage.contentWindow.console.log()
```

This will write to the global page's console.

Comment: Unfortunately, any errors in a popover script are not reported in the global page's console. Perhaps you could use try...catch(e) to write error messages to there.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful workaround. I have filled bug to apple.

Answer (score 4):

```
Stumbled here, looking for something else with popovers ;)
```

If you right click somewhere in the popover, there is now an *Inspect Element* contextual menu point. Here's the kicker: It'll be constrained to the size of the popover window in the same way as if the popover was a "true" window. Have fun with that.

Comment: Not so. Just click the standard icon for detaching the web inspector.

Answer (score 4):

console.log() does work for Popovers.

But not to the global console.  Use the inspect Element on the Popover and you will get it's private console.

[image]

---

[image]

---

Also if you have inline JS in your popover html you can use the Debugger and it's tools like breakpoints

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To debug,  , dynamic create a windows and put your popover.html there,  instead of putting your popover.html in the popover. After debug, put it back.

```
safari.application.addEventListener("command", OpenPopUp, false);    
function OpenPopUp(event) {
var newTab = safari.application.openBrowserWindow().activeTab.url = safari.extension.baseURI + "your_pop_up.html";
}
```

This is my first time posting post in stackoverflow. (From Hong Kong) please give me some vote la.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can debug a popover. The popover is just a small webpage, just rightclick on it and inspect it like a normal webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on popover view and from the context menu chose "Inspect Element".
This is the console of the popover DOM page. 
You can see errors, debug, inspect as a normal web page.