# Safari Desktop Extension Dev - Web Inspector Disappears for Popup

Tags: safari-extension

There's an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998535/how-to-debug-safari-extension-popover) on this but it doesn't answer the issue that I'm facing.

I can right click on the extension popup and "Inspect Element" which opens the web inspector in its own window. However, as soon as I move focus back to the main window that actually has the popup, it disappears along with its inspector. It doesn't matter how I move the focus back to the main window. Clicking on the area that has the popup doesn't help. Neither does choosing the window from the window menu. Whatever I do the popup disappears along with the inspector so there is no way to continue following a flow on the popup and see what's happening in the inspector.

Any ideas?

Thanks.